# Pascal: Interfaced Class, to Double, to Interface instance

Tags: class, pointers, interface, freepascal

This is a bit of an extension on another of my questions. I've got a DLL that is supposed to interface with Game Maker, which uses `Double` and `PChar`.

I have to convert my objects to `Double`s (references) to pass back and forth with Game Maker.

I have 2 Classes: `TBitmap` and `TWindow`. Each implements `IBlittable`. This means that methods operating on `IBlittable`s can use both, however here's the problem:

Here's how I create them:

```
{Creation of Bitmaps and Windows}

function CreateBitmap(W, H: Double): Double; STDCall;
var
  TBM: TBitmap;
begin
  TBM := TBitmap.Create(Floor(W), Floor(H));
  CreateBitmap := Double(Integer(TBM));
end;

function GetWindowByHWND(Handle: Double): Double; STDCall;
var
  ReturnVal: TWindow;
begin
  ReturnVal := TWindow.Create(Floor(Handle));
  GetWindowByHWND := Double(Integer(ReturnVal));
end;
```

And here's how I am *trying* to operate on them:

```
function SetPixel(Handle, X, Y, Color: Double): Double; STDCall;
var
  <stuff>
begin
  Blittable := IBlittable(Floor(Handle)); //This!
  <set the pixel>
  SetPixel := 0;
end;
```

When I cast the `Floor(Handle)` to IBlittable, it segfaults and crashes.

When I cast it to what it previously was (a TWindow or a TBitmap) it works fine. How do I circumvent this problem?

I really don't want to rewrite all the methods specifically (that'd be pretty redundant and lame)

Comment: Why are you storing pointers in *doubles*? That makes no sense at all. Especially using floor, double only has 53 bit precision, so it will never work on a 64-bit system with 64bit precision. Also, are you using CORBA or COM interfaces?

Comment: @BeniBela Game Maker is a piece of software that you can extend with DLLs. It only uses `Double`s for communicating with DLL, so I'm forced  to use them. It's also guaranteed to be 32 bit. Quite hacky and dumb, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to change the types in the creation functions:

```
function CreateBitmap(W, H: Double): Double; STDCall;
var
  TBM: IBlittable; //See
begin
  TBM := TBitmap.Create(Floor(W), Floor(H));
  CreateBitmap := Double(Integer(TBM));
end;

function GetWindowByHWND(Handle: Double): Double; STDCall;
var
  ReturnVal: IBlittable; //Here too
begin
  ReturnVal := TWindow.Create(Floor(Handle));
  GetWindowByHWND := Double(Integer(ReturnVal));
end;
```